# Trouble with ARRAffinity and Instance Balancing

Tags: javascript, c#, azure

I have a little problem
My Website utilizes the ARR Instance Affinity and i'm trying to understand how it works.
My customers seems to enter the same instance in the morning, but when all of them start to work, the instance becomes heavily loaded and the customers get a slow website.
In the meantime, i have a good amount of instances(sometimes i enable about 5 instances).
But then i discovered that if i deleted the ARRAffinity cookie on my browser(Chrome), the next reload on the page, it gets me another instance on Azure.

My main question is: How can i redirect a customer to another instance?

Thanks in advance for the help, and sorry if i made any mistakes with my English.

Comment: Before you get wrecked by moderators : add some code, and show what you have tried ;)

Comment: I would like to show some code, but i dont have much knowledge about this. This website is from my company and i dont know where they are declaring this. I'm trying to find a way to reload this specific Cookie on browser.

Answer (score 0):

The below link has the details for enabling/disabling ARR affinity, assuming you are using  Azure App Service.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/06/03/setting-application-request-routing-arr-affinity-for-your-azure-app-service/

The below link has some helpful information.
https://joonasw.net/view/arr-affinity-in-azure-app-service